# PHP and SQL Select Statements

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select

I am learning PHP and can't seem to find instuctions that I can get into a working sql select.  I'm just trying to learn the fundamentals.  I have a basic php page with a text box and a submit button.  I'm really just using the button to execute a simple query I am trying.  Nothing seems to happen and every resource I have found online doesn't seem to tell the whole story (or I'm just missing some of it).

This is what I have in my testing page.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks :-)

```
<?php
    $serverName = "some-sqlserver";
    $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"123MyDatabase");
    /* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
    $conn = mssql_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( mssql_errors(), true));
    }
    $tsql = "SELECT [Col1]
    FROM [123MyDatabase].[dbo].[vw_somesqlview]";
    //WHERE soemcolumn LIKE '%' + ? + '%'";
    //$params = array( $_REQUEST['col1'] );
    $getCol1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    if ( $getCol1 != null){ 
        //die( FormatErrors( mssql_errors()))
        echo "<h2>Results:</h2>";
        echo $getCol1 ;
        echo "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "couldnt do it";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Add error checking to the query too or check the error logs.

Comment: if you are learning, best to stay away from `mysql_*` which is deprecated for good security reasons, and will be removed from php 7.  Try to learn with PDO and prepared statements. Look it up, plenty of examples.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Seems they're mixing APIs *Sam* - `sqlsrv_query` should be `mssql_query`. Least, that's what it seems to be.

Comment: And regardless of what API they're using, they should need to fetch the row by e.g. `*_fetch_array()`.

Comment: I honestly don't know which API you **should** be using here. Very unclear.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg OP is not using MySQL. OP's using MS SQL Server

Comment: @Machavity ... duhhh my bad ... more security reasons

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use [sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) and not `mssql_connect`. Never mix and match your function families

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Next, you need to parse your query result with something like [sqlsrv_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php)

```
while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($getCol1)) {
  echo $obj->Col1;
}
```

Comment: Lordie; this one could swing either way.

Comment: Yeah. I just picked one and ran with it. Neither seems to be deprecated. Definitely can't mix and match tho

Comment: True. --- *"I just picked one and ran with it."* - I'd of just "ran" ;-) lol

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried this, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  No matter what I put, when I hit submit, I get nothing.  I can get the echo of the dummy field (to be used for parms eventually). but nothing from the sql query.

Comment: Try this after the query then `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());`

Comment: Hey, all.  I've tried all this and nothing is working still.  The php page loads with a form field and submit button, but I get no results or errors, no matter what I do.  It's like php/sql isn't configured right, but I don't know how to figure out what is missing.  When I run phpinfo() there is no sqlsrv section to it.  I don't even know where to start, as I've been going around in circles.  Getting dizzy! lol

Comment: @missscripty I would ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) about how to configure PHP for `sqlsrv`

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to start looking for where I can troubleshoot the configuration lol

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the standard Windows [ODBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx) with PDO which comes equipped usually on install of your SQL Server.

```
<?php

$server="some-sqlserver";
$username="some-user";
$password="some-password";
$database="123MyDatabase";

# open the connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;
                     database=$database",$username,$password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_somesqlview";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    echo $row;
}

# close the connection
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have't specified Db password. Follow below article link which benefits you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp